# Invalid lvalue in Assignment error in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting an error described in the title when I try to run my code with this line:

```
(int**)newPtr = *(list + index);
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

These are my declarations

```
int index; 
int* newPtr;
static int* list;
```

Comment: Is the declaration of `newPtr` `int* newPtr` or `(int**)newPtr`? You show both...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in the code:

- newPtr is declared as a pointer-to-integer, but you are casting it to pointer-to-pointer-to-integer which is wrong.
- list+index is also a pointer-to-integer to *(list+index) is an integer pointed to by (list+index). But you are trying to assign that to newPtr (which is also casted to wrong type as above).

Possibly you intended to do this:

```
newPtr = list+index;
```

and get a pointer-to-integer located at list + index-th location.

Answer (score 0):

*(list + index) returns an int. If you want a pointer out, just use

```
newPtr = list + index;
```

int** means a pointer to an int pointer, that seems to have no business in there.